# trying to remap f9 to insert key

Tags: xmodmap

I have a small laptop which doesn't have a full keyboard and I would like to insert with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to insert from the X clipboard but I don't have an <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. So I figured I just look it up the keycode for <kbd>F9</kbd> with `xev`(it was 75) and just remap the key with `xmodmap` in the following way:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Insert"
```

which should work but it didn't. So I'm stuck now. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

You must add at least one column.

```sh
# set Key and Shift+Key
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Insert Insert"
# set all
xmodmap -e "keycode 75 = Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert"
```

> Each keycode is followed by the keysym it is mapped to. The above
>   example indicates that the keycode 57 is mapped to the lowercase n,
>   while the uppercase N is mapped to keycode 57 plus Shift.
>
> Each keysym column in the table corresponds to a particular
>   combination of modifier keys:
>
> ```
> 1. Key
> 2. Shift+Key
> 3. mode_switch+Key
> 4. mode_switch+Shift+Key
> 5. AltGr+Key
> 6. AltGr+Shift+Key
> ```

-- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap#Keymap_table